# How do the server side commands configured in SSH authorized_keys process the incoming data?

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

Some utilities like git and Gitolite can restrict what commands an SSH key can run by making modifications to the `authorized_key` files.

Gitolite for instance changes modifies the entry in the `authorized_keys` file  thus:

```
command="/usr/bin/gitolite/src/gitolite-shell username",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty
```

As this command is running on the receiving end it has to process the stream of data coming over the SSH connection.

How do commands like this process the incoming data, eg read the incoming data stream and send it to whatever directories or processes that utilize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do it like any other command run by SSH. SSH connects its stdin/stdout/stderr on the client to the stdin/stdout/stderr to the command started on the server. Then the command can read data from stdin as it usually would have, and send data via stdout and stderr as it usually would have.

Being restricted by `authorized_keys` makes no difference, except that TTY allocation may be disabled as in the specific case given in the question (as are port forwarding and other things), so even if you had asked for a TTY, it wouldn't be created.

It would be no different if you'd actually run

```
ssh some-server /usr/bin/gitolite/src/gitolite-shell username
```

It's just that in this case the server ignores what you'd specified and runs the command set in `authorized_keys`.